# Wordpress, Nested queries in get_pages

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have a page structure like this.

```
    Portfolio
    - Residential
    - - Resident 1
    - - Resident 2
    - - Resident 3
    - Commercial
    - - Commercial 1
    - - Commercial 2
    - - Commercial 3
```

The grandchild pages Resident 1 - Commercial 3 have post thumbnails

I have a template for the Portfolio page where i would like to display the 'Residential' and 'Commerical' pages with their child pages like so.

```
<div class="grid">
    <h2>Residential</h2>
    <ul>
        <li> Resident 1 post_thumbnail</li>
        <li> Resident 2 post_thumbnail</li>
        <li> Resident 3 post_thumbnail</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <h2>Commercial</h2>
    <ul>
        <li> Commercial 1 post_thumbnail</li>
        <li> Commercial 2 post_thumbnail</li>
        <li> Commercial 3 post_thumbnail</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using get_pages and I have the div's created for 'Residential' and 'Commercial'

```
<?php

$portfolio_sections = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'child_of'    => $post->ID,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'sort_order'  => 'ASC',
    'parent'      => $post->ID
);

$sections = get_pages($portfolio_sections);

foreach ($sections as $section) { ?>
    <div class="grid">
        <h2><?php echo $section->post_title; ?></h2>

        //Create Child pages

    </div><!--.grid-->
<?php } ?>
```

My problem is creating the child pages in the 'ul' list

I tried using a second foreach loop but this didn't work and I don't know if this is the correct way

```
<?php

$portfolio_sections = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'child_of'    => $post->ID,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'sort_order'  => 'ASC',
    'parent'      => $post->ID
);

$sections = get_pages($portfolio_sections);

foreach ($sections as $section) { ?>
    <div class="grid">
        <h2><?php echo $section->post_title; ?></h2>
        <ul class="imageGrid">
            <?php
            $portfolio_pages = array(
                'post_type'   => 'page',
                'child_of'    => $section->ID,
                'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                'sort_order'  => 'ASC',
                'parent'      => $section->ID
            );

            $pages = get_pages($portfolio_pages);

            foreach ($pages as $page) { ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, "thumbnail"); ?>
                        <span><?php echo get_the_title($page->ID); ?></span></a>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div><!--.grid-->
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have a bug per the documentation for [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages). The parameter `child_of` lists the sub-pages of the supplied ID while `parent` lists pages that have the provided single page only ID as parent. So by supplying it in both queries you're going to generate no results in the query. I'd recommend updating the 2 argument blocks as follows:

```
$portfolio_sections = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'child_of'    => $post->ID,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'sort_order'  => 'ASC'
);
```

Then within your foreach for each sub page query:

```
$portfolio_pages = array(
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'sort_order'  => 'ASC',
    'parent'      => $section->ID
);
```